# MySql Update Join two tables SET CASE invalid group function

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, case

Trying to update a table by joining two tables and using a CASE statement.
I get the old **Error Code: 1111 Invalid use of group function**.  Any ideas on how to resolve?

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.ITEM = table2.ITEM)
SET table1.TURNOVERSCORE=CASE
WHEN ((COUNT(table2.ORDER_NUMBER))/12) < 1 AND table1.CAT = 'E' THEN .05
WHEN ((COUNT(table2.ORDER_NUMBER))/12) >= 1 AND ((COUNT(table2.ORDER_NUMBER))/12) < 4 AND table1.CAT = 'E' THEN .5
WHEN ((COUNT(table2.ORDER_NUMBER))/12) >= 4 AND table1.CAT = 'E' THEN 1
WHEN ((COUNT(table2.ORDER_NUMBER))/12) <= 5 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN .05
WHEN ((COUNT(table2.ORDER_NUMBER))/12) >= 6 AND ((COUNT(table2.ORDER_NUMBER))/12) < 11 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN .25
WHEN ((COUNT(table2.ORDER_NUMBER))/12) >= 11 AND ((COUNT(table2.ORDER_NUMBER))/12) < 21 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN .5
WHEN ((COUNT(table2.ORDER_NUMBER))/12) >= 21 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN 1 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are creating a cross join product, which I don't think is allowed when doing an update.

Maybe try aggregating table 2 first, something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 
JOIN (SELECT count(*) as cnt, item FROM table2 GROUP BY item) t2 
ON table1.item = t2.item

SET table1.TURNOVERSCORE=CASE
WHEN t2.cnt/12 < 1 AND table1.CAT = 'E' THEN .05
WHEN t2.cnt/12 >= 1 AND t2.cnt/12 < 4 AND table1.CAT = 'E' THEN .5
WHEN (t2.cnt/12) >= 4 AND table1.CAT = 'E' THEN 1
WHEN (t2.cnt/12) <= 5 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN .05
WHEN (t2.cnt/12) >= 6 AND (t2.cnt/12) < 11 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN .25
WHEN (t2.cnt/12) >= 11 AND (t2.cnt/12) < 21 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN .5
WHEN (t2.cnt/12) >= 21 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN 1 END
```

Comment: I got this to work successfully when entering it directly into a SQL query such was Workbench.  However, it does not work when I am running the query through php? `$turnoverquery = " UPDATE table1 .."; mysql_query($turnoverquery);`

Comment: If it works in workbench then the query is good. Sorry, I've been out of php for too long to help you debug why php is having a problem with it.